# PhantomJS , device size is always 1024

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am unable to change the device size from 1024.
When setting:

```
page.viewportSize = { width: 1366, height: 768 };
```

I am still getting 1024, after

```
var width = page.evaluate(function(){
    return window.screen.width;
}
```

This can be a serious issue, since some media queries are invovled.
Thanks.

Comment: Probably related to this issue: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10619

Comment: Possible duplicate of [viewportSize seems not to work with PhantomJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390859/viewportsize-seems-not-to-work-with-phantomjs)