# Dynamically change viewportSize in PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs, viewport

In order to have PhantomJS create screenshots of a page at different viewport widths, I'd like to adjust it dynamically. This does not work, though:

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 800, height: 600 };

page.open('http://example.com', function (status) {

    page.render('medium.png');

    page.viewportSize = { width: 630, height: 420 };

    page.render('small.png');

    phantom.exit();
});
```

When run with `phantomjs script.js` this produces two identical PNG files `medium.png` and `small.png` at a width of 800px each. Expected behaviour was to have `medium.png` like this and `small.png` at a width of 630px. How can this be achieved?

PS: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25354014/948404) to a similar question produces an error for me. Also [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16746373/948404) to that question suggests quite an ugly workaround I would like to avoid.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. The size is changed for me on Windows with PhantomJS 2.1.1.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu with PhantomJS version 1.9.?. I will try to upgrade. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be possible to set the viewport size and open the page again like this:

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 800, height: 600 };

page.open('http://example.com', function (status) {

    page.render('medium.png');


    page.viewportSize = { width: 630, height: 420 };

    page.open('http://example.com', function (status) {

        page.render('small.png');

        phantom.exit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems to work if you either have the second part inside the callback of the first or wrap it with a `setTimeout`. Thanks!

Comment: I changed it to your recommended way